# annotation to enforce void trait initialization

Tags: scala, initialization, mixins, traits

There are quite a number of questions regarding trait initialization order in scala. I'd like to mark a trait with annotation that states the trait have no initialization code and so may be used without bothering of initialization order.

Something like this:

```
@noinit
trait Funcs[A] {
  val a : A
  def b() : A
  def c(x : A)
}
```

trait `Funcs` just declares some values and function and require no initialization code

How to implement described functionality?

Comment: yes, I've modified the question